# how to highlight checked radio using jquery

Tags: jquery

for static html page

```
$("input:checked").addClass("highlight");
```

works fine . But for ajax populated page its not working.

Is there any better idea how radio box can be highlighted for ajax pages as well.

Comment: How are you calling this piece of code? For example, if it is via a click event, you might need to add a .live method reference so that jquery reevaluates the DOM before attempting to get the checked inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this somewhere before your first AJAX call:

```
$(function() {
  $("body").ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $("input:checked").addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

If you aren't altering their values with JS, then I wouldn't use jQuery at all, just use CSS:

```
input[checked] { background: red }
```

Note this CSS selector will not work in IE6.

Answer (score 2):

After you received the ajax parts, just rerun the command

```
$("input:checked").addClass("highlight");
```

should do the job. Or are there any reasons against?